# Listview and button hidden

Tags: java, android, listview, button, hidden

Well, I try to explain.
I made an application where I have a listview where each row have also two buttons (I have made it with other question posted in this site).
The problem is this:
The two buttons is "start" and "stop". When I click start, a service starts and when I click on stop this service has to stop (I haven't implemented the service for now).
So, when I click start, I would like to hide the start button, in this way I know that the service is started.
How can I do it? Besides, it can be the right choice implements the service in this way?
I have choosen this idea because I need to stop the service when I decide to stop it.

Code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //generate list
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");

        //instantiate custom adapter
        android.widget.ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,0,list);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sara.myapplication.MainActivity">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

row_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="2pt"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:layout_weight="0.49"/>


    <Button
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/start_button"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private int layout;
    private Context context;

    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        context = context;
        layout = resource;
        list = objects;
    }


    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "delete - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do something
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "start - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return view;

    }

}
```

Comment: use pojoclass to maintain the position of the button in the list and then apply addBtn.setVisibility(View.Invisible) to the your button.

Comment: Why not have one button text as **Start** when service is stopped and **Stop** when the service has been started (could even also have it red when stopped and green when started). You would likely have to store the current state somewhere or have some means to determine the state of the service (you may have the same issues with two buttons)

Comment: You have to maintain status of every start button of list view and then you can do it easily. Thanks

Comment: @AngelSara 1st you maintain the position of the item of the listview after that apply this code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You seem to be hiding and showing the button(s) just fine?

Answer (score 0):

you can use some boolean flag value to change the visibility of button on click.

Answer (score 0):

If on your list you have more than one element, then you have to implement a custom adapter and create an ad hoc listner for each element. Use setTag and getTag.
CHange row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/list_item_string"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5pt"
        android:layout_marginTop="2pt"
        android:textSize="10pt"
        android:layout_weight="0.49"/>


    <Button
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/start_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="start"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/start_button"
        android:onClick="stop"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/start_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And in MainAcitivty

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //generate list
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("item1");
        list.add("item2");

        //instantiate custom adapter
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, 0, list);

        //handle listview and assign adapter
        ListView lView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        lView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void start(View v){
        Button b = (Button) v;
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    public void stop(View v){

    }


}
```

ListAdapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
        }

        //Handle TextView and display string from your list
        TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string);
        listItemText.setText(list.get(position));

        //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
        Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
        Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.start_button);

        return view;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "start - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do something
                addBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "delete - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //do something
                addBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

In this way seems working

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the `setVisible(false)` method
Example:

```
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "start - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            addBtn.setVisible(false); // ← Hide the "Start button"
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

To Hide start Button after clicking,

```
 addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "start - Button was clicked for list item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
         addBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have add the "setVisibility"

Comment: yeah, so it seems